# wxWidget - Populating a wxComboBox?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

How can I populate values in a wxComboBox dynamically, I know we can populate it while initializing it like this, but I want to do it e.g. when a user clicks a button

```
wxArrayString   m_arrItems;

// Create common wxArrayString array
m_arrItems.Add( wxT("Solid") );
m_arrItems.Add( wxT("Transparent") );
m_arrItems.Add( wxT("Dot") );

ComboBox1 = new wxComboBox(this, ID_COMBOBOX1, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, m_arrItems, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_COMBOBOX1"));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

See its members inherited from `wxItemContainer`: `Set()`, `Append()`, `Insert()`.

Comment: Choice1->Set(m_arrItems);
 
It Worked

Comment: @SyedMuhammadWaliQadri, but it is not dynamically updating the control. You can do that even when it is created. The event I mentioned are firing exactly when the user clicks on the arrow button, i.e. alow the dynamic filling of the control.

Answer (score -1):

See EVT_COMBOBOX_DROPDOWN/EVT_COMBOBOX_CLOSEUP.

Comment: Is there an explanation why there is a negative vote? Those events where made exactly for the purpose of dynamically updating combo box, i.e. what the OP wants.